# Newly Created Area showing as an Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-express

In my project I already have 5 Areas. I added a new Area Recruitment & all is working well.

But when i right click the IIS Express icon in TaskBar it shows me 2 applications. It shows the newly created Recruitment also. Check the image.

How to remove this?

[image]

Comment: Did you try restarting the iis express?

Comment: @Yasser Yes i restarted IIS Express, still the same thing.

Comment: I commented directly from applicahost.config. `C:\Users\User1\Documents\IISExpress\config`

Comment: You probably should show `<sites>` tag of the configuration file. Meanwhile, you should also tell your Visual Studio version.

Comment: @LexLi I am using Visual Studio Express 2012. Which configuration file you want to see? where is it located?